# drupal module for managing assets like wordpress

Tags: pdf, drupal-7, powerpoint, assets

Is there a drupal 7 module that will allow for managing assets like wordpress' media manager, where as admin, you can upload a pdf/ppt/pps/etc (not just images) and create download links?  Be able to insert any number of assets into body text view or download.  View a list/manage assets used in a node or used globally?

Comment: Did you try googling? There is -amongst several others- one called 'Media' - https://www.drupal.org/project/media

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look.  I did google and found a bunch of solutions, many were not kept up and didn't work well.  That's why I'm asking if anybody has had some success with a particularly good module.

Comment: Well, after trying the Media module, I found it quite buggy and it can't upload anything but image files, contrary to what it claims.   Still can't seem to find a good module at works.